# clientId missing from resource_access field in jwt token when using impersonation

Tags: jwt, keycloak, access-token, impersonation

I'm using Keycloak 14.0.0 and enabled the feature preview of token_exchange in order to do impersonation. After configuring my user in Keycloak to take on the impersonation role on the client "realm-management" (as according to the [documentation][1]), the actual request to do the token exchange fails as the token is not valid.

After some debugging it turns out that the jwt token is indeed malformed:

```
...
  "session_state": "a03aeg0e-b5ce-4a50-9038-c339e50338c4",
  "acr": "1",
  "allowed-origins": [
    "http://0.0.0.0:9180"
  ],
  "scope": "openid identity_provider email admin profile company",
  "permissions": [
    "consented-readonly",
    "readonly",
    "trackingdisabled"
  ],
  "resource_access": {
    ".roles": [
      "impersonation"
    ]
  },
  "email_verified": false,
  "idp": "myidp",
...
```

In the above, please notice the ".roles". I assume this is incorrect. It should be something like:

```
"resource_access": {
    "myclient": {
      "roles": [
      "impersonation"
      ]
    }
```

How can this be fixed?
[1]: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#impersonation

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the configuration of a mapper was incorrect. In this case it was the "client roles" mapper (client scopes -> roles -> mapper -> client roles in keycloak ui) which, in my keycloak setup, had the value of:

```
resource_access..roles
```

This is incorrect as it should contain a clientId placeholder as shown below:

```
resource_access.${client_id}.roles
```

after this change the accessToken includes the actual client resulting in a valid json in the accessToken